# How to remove SmartGit from CentOS7?

Tags: git, centos7, smartgit

I have installed SmartGit on my CentOs7.

By mistake I chose the licensed trial version and it got expired.
I want to use non commercial version.
There are no `settings.xml` or `preferences.yml`.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this [process would help](https://www.syntevo.com/blog/?p=3669):

> From time to time, SmartGit users contact us because their SmartGit has expired and they want to continue to use it free of charge for non-commercial purposes.
>
> The type of usage you have to select on the first SmartGit start.
>
> If you forgot to set the right option and you started an evaluation for commercial purposes,
>
> - exit SmartGit
> - clear SmartGit’s settings directory (see the [documentation](http://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/Installation+and+Files#InstallationandFiles-DefaultLocationofSmartGit%27sSettingsDirectorysettings-dir.default-location))
> - restart SmartGit and select the non-commercial option

In your case, for Linux:

```
${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/smartgit/<major-smartgit-version> 

# if the environment variable XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not defined:
~/.config
```

The [OP Divz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16261948/divz) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328902/how-to-remove-smartgit-from-centos7/68329325?noredirect=1#comment121007485_68329325):

> I removed license file and preferences.yml from .config folder and it works

It is often the case when the remote repository is *not* created empty, but rather initialized with default files.

Comment: I removed license file and preferences.yml from .config folder and it works

Comment: @Divz OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.